# Flutter : How to make dropdown button inside a box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new using a flutter in one of my project i'm trying to put a drop down button somehow it shows error on the widht.

the dropdown also sometimes got an error when changing value and the border sometimes gone.

What i want to build:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41vbk.jpg
What i got :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePJSZ.jpg

This is my code

```
class Data4 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Data4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 150,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Pilihan1(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pilihan1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Pilihan1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pilihan1> createState() => _Pilihan1State();
}

class _Pilihan1State extends State<Pilihan1> {
  @override
  List<String> items = ['Pilih Pengantar', 'Pengantar 1', 'Pengantar 2'];
  String? selectedItem = 'Pilih Pengantar';
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
        width: 310,
        height: 80,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black)),
          ),
          value: selectedItem,
          items: items
              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Text(item, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (item) => setState(() => selectedItem = item),
        ),
      )));
}
```

Comment: Wrap `Pilihan1()` in `Column` widget not a `Row` widget and give width and height using `MediaQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Data4 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Data4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: const [
        DropDownClass(),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

DropDown Class

```
class DropDownClass extends StatefulWidget {
   const DropDownClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
   @override
   State<DropDownClass> createState() => _DropDownClassState();
  }
 
class _DropDownClassState extends State<DropDownClass> {
  List<String> items = ['Pilih Pengantar', 'Pengantar 1', 'Pengantar 2'];
  String? selectedItem = 'Pilih Pengantar';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 310,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, size: 20).paddingOnly(right: 10),
            value: selectedItem,
            items: items
                .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: item,
                      child: Text(item, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)).paddingOnly(left: 10.0),
                    ))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (item) => setState(() => selectedItem = item),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```